# Why do I get `TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<Map> which has only a getter` error?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have a Nest app where I use (besides other stuff) [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/), [MikroORM](https://mikro-orm.io/) and [`nest-mqtt`](https://github.com/microud/nest-mqtt) (actually using it from a [fork](https://github.com/128keaton/nest-mqtt) which fixes it for Nest 8).

Now, the problem lays in using both MikroORM and `nest-mqtt`: when both are imported in a module (`MikroOrmModule.forRoot()` and `MqttModule.forRoot()`), it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<Map> which has only a getter
    at _clone (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/clone/clone.js:162:16)
    at _clone (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/clone/clone.js:162:18)
    at clone (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/clone/clone.js:202:10)
    at Function.copy (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/utils/Utils.js:237:36)
    at MetadataDiscovery.discoverDirectories (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/metadata/MetadataDiscovery.js:137:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at MetadataDiscovery.findEntities (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/metadata/MetadataDiscovery.js:106:9)
    at MetadataDiscovery.discover (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/metadata/MetadataDiscovery.js:53:9)
    at MikroORM.discoverEntities (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/MikroORM.js:87:25)
    at Function.init (/home/ts/mikro-orm-nest-mqtt/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/dist/MikroORM.js:42:9)
```

At first, I thought it is an error in [`clone`](https://github.com/pvorb/clone) (see [this issue](https://github.com/pvorb/clone/issues/117)), however, it does not fail when only one of the the packages (MikroORM or `nest-mqtt`) is imported into a module.

I suspect that the two packages somehow interact/conflict with each other, however, I am lost.

[Here](https://github.com/tukusejssirs/nest-test/tree/mikro-orm_nest-mqtt) you can find a minimal reproduction. Tested with `npm v8.1.2` and `node v16.13.1` and `node v17.2.0`. Also note that it does not matter if the MQTT is actually running. Also change the MikroORM config in `src/mikro-orm.config.ts` as needed.

Also see [this discussion](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/discussions/2597) at MikroORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@B4nan](https://github.com/B4nan) user at GitHub [found](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/discussions/2597#discussioncomment-1912286) the root of this issue: `collections` package patches some global Node objects like `Map`, `Set`, `Array`. The issue was already reported at [mqttjs/MQTT.js#1392](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1392).

Last version without `collections` dependency is `v4.2.8` and last commit without it is [8aa2f8d](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/commit/8aa2f8d82f4b74706882cd61b36b240e04511b44). Current workaround for me is to use that version until they remove `collections` from dependencies.

**Update:** There is a new PR that should remove `collections` dependency: [mqttjs/MQTT.js#1396](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/pull/1396).

**Update 2:** The PR is already merged and `mqtt@4.3.4` is working as expected.